# What does "all-yes" mean in ffmpeg Makefile

Tags: ffmpeg, makefile

In ffmpeg Makefile,

https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/Makefile#L37

https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/Makefile#L189

It defined phony targets "all" and "all-yes", but I can't find prerequisites and command of "all-yes" by searching whole ffmpeg directory. So can anyone help to explain what "all-yes" exactly means?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: `all-yes` is not special.  It has only the significance that a given makefile attributes to it.

Comment: FFmpeg appears to have a `configure` script.  Presumably that writes or modifies files that affect the build.  You could consider using it to configure `FFmpeg`, and *then* looking for `all-yes` among the files in the source directory.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for your reply. I have used `grep all-yes .` in ffmpeg source directory to search it, however `all-yes` only appears in Makefile of root directory without defining.

Comment: @FLT, I am inclined to think that when the project is configured by running its `configure` script, that will change.  If not, then the project is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another "all" target in the "include $(SRC_PATH)/fftools/Makefile": https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/fftools/Makefile#L30

```
$(foreach P,$(AVPROGS-yes),$(eval $(call DOFFTOOL,$(P))))
all: $(AVPROGS)
fftools/ffprobe.o fftools/cmdutils.o: libavutil/ffversion.h | fftools
OUTDIRS += fftools
```

[4.11 Multiple Rules for One Target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Rules.html)

> There can only be one recipe to be executed for a file. If more than one rule gives a recipe for the same file, make uses the last one given and prints an error message. (As a special case, if the file’s name begins with a dot, no error message is printed. This odd behavior is only for compatibility with other implementations of make… you should avoid using it). Occasionally it is useful to have the same target invoke multiple recipes which are defined in different parts of your makefile; you can use double-colon rules (see Double-Colon) for this.

There are two targets and *make* only uses the last one, so you could delete the "all-yes" or delete "all:all-yes" then use "make all" command, and it has no effect on the compilation. the command line "all:all-yes" is just ensure the "all" is the default target.

Comment: Thank for your answer. It helps me a lot.